# Define bean depending on Spring's bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

When using Spring Boot, a lot of beans are created implicitly by Spring Boot itself. For example, when I link the `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` dependency, the `jedisConnectionFactory` bean is created automatically under the hood.

What I'm looking for is the way to define my custom bean with a dependency on such an implicit bean, e.g. `new MyService( jedisConnectionFactory )`. The problem is that I don't have a variable or a method which would be resolved to that implicit bean.

For now I've come up with the following solution: create a separate `BeanConfig` class, autowire/inject `ApplicationContext` into it and then retrieve the required bean with [`ApplicationContext.getBean( Class<T> )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) method call:

```
@Bean
public Transport eventTransport() {
    final JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = context.getBean( JedisConnectionFactory.class );
    return new RedisTransport( jedisConnectionFactory.getHostName(), jedisConnectionFactory.getPort() );
}
```

Is there any integrated way to get a reference to the beans defined internally? So that I could move this bean definition to `MyApplication` class without injecting the `ApplicationContext` instance.

Comment: Just add them as a method argument of the `@Bean` method. `public Transport eventTransport(JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory)`. Generally when you need to rely on the `ApplicationContext` (or `BeanFactory`) to retrieve beans you are, generally speaking, doing it wrong (if you aren't a framework/extension developer that is).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I get it about using the context, that's why asking :) I think defining the method argument is right what I was looking for, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as a rule of thumb if you starting to resort to the `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` to obtain beans you are, generally speaking, doing it wrong (at least when simply developing an application with Spring).

When using `@Bean` on a method, effectively making it a factory method for those beans, you can use 0 or more method arguments. (This is also explained in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-dependencies)). The arguments are resolved against the context and will have the beans injected (or fail starting if it cannot be found).

So in your case you can simply add `JedisConnnectionFactory` (or maybe the `ConnectionFactory` interface) as a method argument for your `eventTransport` method.

```
@Bean
public Transport eventTransport(final JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
    return new RedisTransport( jedisConnectionFactory.getHostName(), jedisConnectionFactory.getPort() );
}
```

This also allows Spring to resolve dependencies between beans instead of hoping the bean is already constructed and fully ready for use.

Comment: A special thanks for the documentation link - somehow I failed to find that on my own

Answer (score 0):

If `JedisConnectionFactory` class is getting instantiated by **spring** then you can simply `autowire` this instance at the class level and use the same to create `RedisTransport` object.

```
@Autowired
private JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory;

@Bean
public Transport eventTransport() {
    return new RedisTransport( jedisConnectionFactory.getHostName(), jedisConnectionFactory.getPort() );
}
```

Comment: Even better, just put it as a method argument, that way Spring is better able to determine the order of the beans.